# Как остановить выполнение страницы на phatomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Проверяю страничку на доступность через phantomjs. Пример полностью идентичный примеру на гитхабе:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netsniff.js
В случае если на странице бесконечный яваскрипт, то данный скрипт зависнет и будет ждать до бесконечности. Как сделать так, чтобы он прекращал парсить страницу по истечению 20-30 секунд

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в конец callback'а для page.open таймер с выходом из скрипта:

```
page.open(url, function(status) {
  ...
  setTimeout(function() {
    phantom.exit();
  }, 20000); // 20 сек
});
```